# Store PHP variables in an array, until the loop ends

Tags: php

```
<ul>
<?php 
foreach (glob("*") as $filename) {
    ?>

  <li><a href="<?php echo $filename;?>"><?php echo $filename; ?></a></li>
<?php 
}
?>
</ul>
```

I get the output as

```
home.php
css
contact.php
```

An so on! My question is can I store all the `$filename` I get into an array??
Such as

```
$files=array(home.php,css,contact.php)
```

If i add new file I need it in an Array!
I tried `$files=array($filename);` but it only make the last file as array!!
Anyone can help??
Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to initialize your array as blank as so:

```
$files=array();
```

Then in your loop you need to use `array_push()` to *add* the files to the array like this:

```
array_push($files, $filename);
```

Once the loop is complete, the array `$files` will contain all the file names.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you want to do something like this?

```
$filenames = array();           
$all_files = array("home.php", "css", "contact.php");

            foreach ($all_files as $filename) {
                $filenames[] = $filename;
            }

            print_r($filenames);`
```

Or maybe you want to add all items concatenated, separated by comma?